# How to call mysql stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, call

I want to call a Mysql stored procedure from c# . I am running the same procedure in mysql query browser finely . This is about getting a maturity date from given input year , month , days  with current date . 
 [This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYQOG.png)

```
      DELIMITER $$

         DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `passbook`.`maturity_date` $$
         CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `maturity_date`(IN `stdate` 
         DATE, IN `adyear` INT(4), IN `amonth` INT(2), IN `adays` INT(2), INOUT 
         `matdate` DATE)
         NO SQL
         Begin
         declare new_date , pstdate date;

         set new_date = stdate;

          if adyear > 0 then

          SELECT date_add(stdate, INTERVAL adyear year) into pstdate;

          set new_date = pstdate;
          end if;


           if amonth > 0 then

SELECT date_add(new_date, INTERVAL amonth MONTH) into pstdate;
set new_date = pstdate;
end if;

if adays > 0 then

SELECT date_add(new_date, INTERVAL adays DAY) into pstdate;
set new_date = pstdate;
end if;


Set matdate = new_date;
Select matdate;
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

[image: getting error Image]

Comment: It would be nice to know how you want the output, collection, data-table, etc. What is your C# looking like?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
            var ConnectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword";            
            var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            var storedProcedureName = "SPName";

    //add parameters with value and type here
            sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "@adyear", Value = adyear});
            sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "@amonth", Value = amonth});
            sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, ParameterName = "@adys ", Value = adys });

    //execute store procedure here
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, connection) { CommandTimeout = 160, CommandType = commandType })
            using (var dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);

                connection.Open();
                dataAdaptor.Fill(dS);
            }
```

also you can use `Mysql.Data` i believe it is the easiest way to do. You don't need anything else to work with mysql database.

```
PM> Install-Package MySql.Data
```

you can store the connection string in a file. just create a file and put your connection string on it. then read it in a static class. something like this:

```
CS = File.ReadAllText(YourDataBaseConfigFilePath);
```

then use it as your connection string.

Comment: Hello , Where to add  parameters adyear,amonth,adys ??

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad I will check it out

Comment: you are welcome. please also consider using Mysql.Data

Comment: i am getting the error  . I am unable to show the error image here . so i am posting modified code here . Unable to post code here too. :(

Comment: hi @mohammad where to define connection string ? how would it know  the mysql server , schema etc. ?? . Guide please .

Comment: dear @AnandCoolkarni you can store your connection string in your web.config and always encrypt it.this link will show you how to encrypt parts of your configuration file: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: i am still  there only . No progress in by the way my connection string will be like this <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=dbname;uid=bbb;password=aaaa;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: @mohammad i have tried for 3 day but i am unable to get the connection string data

Comment: dear @AnandCoolkarni. i updated my answer but honestly I'm little confused. i guess your main problem solved and you have a new problem now. if its true please close this topic by marking my post as a answer and then open new one.

Comment: NO Sir , No new problem i have not run the stored procedure yet. In your stored procedure calling code there is no  Variable defined for   " cs  " .  Then how will it consider the connection string .

Comment: dear @AnandCoolkarni i updated my answer. hope it solve your problem. here you can read more about connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/